# Searching through a file in Python

Tags: python, file

Say that I have a file of restaurant names and that I need to search through said file and find a particular string like "Italian". How would the code look if I searched the file for the string and print out the number of restaurants with the same string?

```
f = open("/home/ubuntu/ipynb/NYU_Notes/2-Introduction_to_Python/data/restaurant-names.txt", "r")
content = f.read()
f.close()
lines = content.split("\n")
with open("/home/ubuntu/ipynb/NYU_Notes/2-Introduction_to_Python/data/restaurant-names.txt") as f:
      print ("There are", len(f.readlines()), "restaurants in the dataset")
with open("/home/ubuntu/ipynb/NYU_Notes/2-Introduction_to_Python/data/restaurant-names.txt") as f:
        searchlines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "GREEK" in line: 
        for l in searchlines[i:i+3]: print (l),
        print
```

Comment: Any information on how the file is formatted?

Comment: Sounds like it looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: @BLang the file is formatted with one restaurant name per line and contains nothing else

Comment: EDIT: I've added the code I have so far, its just that I wanted a more efficient way to search the file and count up the number of restaurants containing a similar string

Comment: Why are you opening the file so many times? Also do you want exact matches or partial and do you have many words to count?

Comment: Provide an example of what the data set file looks like so i can better help you. I dont want to be down voted anymore.

Comment: Also why are you doing `for l in searchlines[i:i+3]:` after you find a match?

Comment: @Padriac Cunningham I haven't cleaned up the code yet so thats why there so many opening of the file. I want exact matches rather than partial in this case and there are over 2000 lines with an average 13 words per line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count all the words using a Counter dict and then do lookups for certain words:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

f_name = "/home/ubuntu/ipynb/NYU_Notes/2-Introduction_to_Python/data/restaurant-names.txt"


with open(f_name) as f:
    #  sum(1 for _ in f) -> counts lines
    print ("There are", sum(1 for _ in f), "restaurants in the dataset")
    # reset file pointer back to the start
    f.seek(0)
    # get count of how many times each word appears, at most once per line
    cn = Counter(word.strip(punctuation).lower() for line in f for word in set(line.split()))
    print(cn["italian"]) # no keyError if missing, will be 0
```

we use `set(line.split())` so if a word appeared twice for a certain restaurant, we would only count it once. That looks for exact matches, if you are also looking to match partials like `foo` in `foobar` then it is going to be more complex to create a dataset where you can efficiently lookup multiple words.

If you really just want to count one word all you need to do is use *sum* how many times the substring appears in a line:

```
f_name = "/home/ubuntu/ipynb/NYU_Notes/2-Introduction_to_Python/data/restaurant-names.txt"

with open(f_name) as f:
    print ("There are", sum(1 for _ in f), "restaurants in the dataset")
    f.seek(0)
    sub = "italian"
    count = sum(sub in line.lower() for line in f)
```

If you want exact matches, you would need the split logic again or to use a regex with word boundaries.

Answer (score -1):

You input the file as a string.
Then use the count method of strings.
Code:

```
#Let the file be taken as a string in s1
print s1.count("italian")
```